# Should I write "partially ... and the rest" or just "partially ... and"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-choice

> In addition, the information about the sensor is  **partially**
>   obtained  from the data sheets provided by the vendor and  **the
>   rest** from scientific research .

Which structure is correct for the sentence above?

> [...] partially and the rest [...]

*or*

> partially and [...]

Answer (score 1):

They don't mean the same thing.

> In addition, the information about the sensor is **partially** obtained from the data sheets provided by the vendor **and the rest from** scientific research.

This means *partially* is added to *the rest* (everything else). The total is 100%.

> In addition, the information about the sensor is **partially** obtained from the data sheets provided by the vendor **and from** scientific research.

This applies *partially* to both *data sheets* and to *scientific research*. There could be another type of data not mentioned, but you can't tell without additional context.